# How to involve C++/WinRT lib in C# UWP App on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, uwp, c++-winrt

I have a C++/WinRT lib (dll/lib/winmd...), I want to use it in my C# UWP App。

- I want to query how to involve it in my C# UWP project. (where to add reference of lib/winmd files in VS2022).
- Since C++/WinRT is self language projection, so I can use it in C# code directly, am I right?

Thanks.

Comment: [Generate a C# projection from a C++/WinRT component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/net-projection-from-cppwinrt-component).

Comment: Thanks IInspectable,
The C++/WinRT in this guide is "source code project" and the target app is ".NET 6 console application".  it works from my side. But my requirement is involve a pre-built C++/WinRT lib in to C# UWP app.  I try as "Generate a C# projection from a C++/WinRT component" mentioned, but find options are diff, And I don't know how to config correctly!!

Comment: In VS2022,   I found how to add "winmd" as reference, but after I add xxx.winmd as reference, I found the winmd file is located in References node,  but when I compile project,  it cannot generated a xxx.h file by cppwinrt.exe automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it seems that it is not able to directly add a C++/WinRT component as a reference to a C# UWP app directly via Visual Studio. But you could do this manually by modifying the csproj file and the manifest file. You could go through this Github link: [Unable to add C++/WinRT Runtime Component to UWP C# Application](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/425). In that link, Code-ScottLe tried to modify the csproj file and Scottj1s gives suggestions about how to make it work.

In short, you need to modify the c# project and adding

```
 <ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\projectname\project.vcxproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And then change the c# manifest:

```
<Extensions>
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
  <InProcessServer>
    <Path>projectname.dll</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="projectname.classname" ThreadingModel="both"/>
  </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

For more details, please go through the link: [Unable to add C++/WinRT Runtime Component to UWP C# Application](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/425)